# Multi-variable for loops

Tags: java, loops

Im having some trouble with writing a multi-variable for loop.

How would I write these for loops as one for loop.

```
for (x1pos = 5; x1pos <= 105; x1pos+=4)
{
    for (x2pos = 105; x2pos >= 5; x2pos-=4)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: And what does this code do? How would you vary both of your loop variables without the nested loop?

Comment: _Why_ would you write them as one loop? I haven't verified any of the answers, but none of them are as clear as the nested loops you wrote.

Comment: To clarify, do you want code that acts the same as your nested loops, but only contains one `for` loop?

Answer (score 1):

So first, let's take a look at the output your loops produce. I'll put a `System.out.printf("%d, %d%n", x1pos, x2pos)` in the inner loop. The output looks something like this:

```
5, 105
5, 101
5, 97
...
5, 5
9, 105
9, 101
9, 107
...
105, 5
```

So, what's going on here?

- initially, `x1pos` is 5 and `x2pos` is 105
- `x2pos` goes down by 4 each time
- ... except that if it reaches 5, it "resets" to 105 and `x1pos` is incremented by 4
- ... and if this happens when `x1pos` is already 105, the pattern ends

Okay, cool. Now we just need to implement that logic in Java:

```
// initial values; and x2pos goes down by 4 each time
for (int x1pos = 5, x2pos = 105; ; x2pos -= 4) {
  if (x2pos < 5) {      // if x1pos reaches 5...
    if (x1pos >= 105) { // ...then if x1pos reached 105 already, we're done.
      break;
    } else {
      x2pos = 105;      // Otherwise, reset x2pos and increment x1pos.
      x1pos += 4;
    }
  }

  // Now you can do whatever with the values, such as:
  System.out.printf("%d, %d%n", x1pos, x2pos);
}
```

Note:

- I initially set `x1pos` and `x2pos`, which seems intuitive enough
- I don't have any condition for stopping in the `for` clause; I tuck this away inside the loop. (This could be done as a condition in the `for`, but this way is simpler)
- the action taken after each loop only decrements `x2pos`, since that's the only variable that always changes
- The "except that..." logic from above is put inside the body of the `for`, instead of in the `for(...)` itself. Again, you could probably do it all in the `for` (with a helper method like `x1pos = nextX1Pos(x1pos, x2pos)` but this is simpler

As you can see, this is more code, and *much* less clear than your two loops. **You should just use the nested loops.** There's no way to loop over all of those combinations that's more efficient, and the nested loops are much clearer and less bug-prone.

Answer (score 0):

`for (x1pos = 5, x2pos = 105; x1pos <= 105 && x2pos >= 5; x1pos+= 4, x2pos-=4) {`

Keep in mind that `x1pos` and `x2pos` have to be of the same type.

Comment: While this answer isnt as detailed or useful to the OP, this helped me with remembering the syntax of a multivariable for loop for use in a different situation than the one that OP asked about